# How to play a sound in foreground under lock screen?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I play sounds with `MediaElement`. But I want it to continue playing if the screen is locked.

I read [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/01/running-a-windows-phone-application-under-the-lock-screen.aspx) that we should do it this way:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

I have added it to the page's constructor, but nothing happens, and after locking, it stops the sound.

I don't want to play it even when the app isn't in foreground. but just under the lock screen.
(It's WP8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may do the trick

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```